# How to prevent validation appearing at initialization for angular2-dart and angular2-forms

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am earnestly trying to learn angular2-dart since its beta version. I have a form with the following code:

### html

```
<div class = "container">
  <div [hidden] = "isSubmitted">
    <h1>Hero Form</h1>
    <div class="md-button"><ng-content></ng-content></div>
    <form (ngSubmit) = "onSubmit()"
          #heroForm = "ngForm">
      {{diagnostic}}
      <div class = "form-group">
        <label for = "name">Name</label>
        <input type = "text"
               class = "form-control"
               required
               [(ngModel)] = "model.name"
               ngControl = "name"
               #name = "ngForm"
               #spy>
        <p [hidden] = "name.valid"
           class = "alert alert-danger">
          Name is required
        </p>
        TODO: remove this: {{spy.className}}
      </div>

      <div class = "form-group">
        <label for = "alterEgo">Alter Ego</label>
        <input type = "text"
               class = "form-control"
               [(ngModel)] = "model.alterEgo"
               ngControl = "alterEgo">
      </div>

      <div class = "form-group">
        <label for = "power">Hero Power</label>
        <select class = "form-control"
                required
                [(ngModel)] = "model.power"
                ngControl = "power">
          <option *ngFor = "#p of powers"
                  [value] = "p">{{p}}
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <button type = "submit"
              class = "btn btn-default"
              [disabled] = "!heroForm.form.valid">Submit
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

### .dart

```
library hero_form.hero_form_component;

import 'package:angular2/angular2.dart';
import 'package:angular2_forms/hero.dart';
import 'package:jsonx/jsonx.dart';

//import 'package:angular2_material/src/components/input/input.dart';
//import 'package:angular2_material/src/components/button/button.dart';

const List<String> _powers = const [
  'Really Smart',
  'Super Flexible',
  'Super Hot',
  'Weather Changer'
];

bool isDevelopment = true;


@Component(
    selector: 'hero-form',
    templateUrl: 'hero_form_component.html',
// Soon specifying directives here will be unnecessary.
    directives: const [CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES] )
class HeroFormComponent {
  List<String> get powers => _powers;
  bool isSubmitted = false;

  Hero model = new Hero( 18, '', _powers[0], 'Chuck Overstreet' );

  // TODO: Remove this when we're done
  String get diagnostic
  {
    if(isDevelopment)
    {
      return 'DIAGNOSTIC: ${encode(model, indent: ' ')}';
    }
    return '';
  }

  onSubmit( ) {
    // use isSubmitted to to validate and publish instance
    isSubmitted = true;
  }
}
```

When the component is run, the name input already shows the invalid status. What is the best practice for avoiding this. I would prefer that the validation is not shown initially, but after gaining focus.

Cheers,
Teddy

Answer (score 1):

This would probably be the easiest:

```html
<input type = "text"
               class = "form-control"
               required
               [(ngModel)] = "model.name"
               ngControl = "name"
               #name = "ngForm"
               #spy>
        <p [hidden] = "name.valid || name.pristine"
           class = "alert alert-danger">
          Name is required
        </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you should leverage the state of the form and more particularly attributes `touched` and `pristine`. To access the state for a specific field, simply leverage `ngControl` and create a corresponding local variable (with a `#`). You can then use the variable (i.e. the state of the form field) to check if it has been updated or touched.

Here are the attributes that would fit your needs:

> `untouched` True if control has not lost focus yet.
>
> `touched` True if control has lost focus.
>
> `pristine` True if user has not interacted with the control yet.
>
> `dirty` True if user has already interacted with the control.

See this doc on angular.io regarding forms for more details: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry